# Power Bi: Min and Max Row Values for measures in a separate table

Tags: matrix, powerbi, max, min

Got stuck with a quite, in my opinion, complicated task. There is a matrix of Measures (Rows) for Countries (Columns), which looks as following:

[image: Matrix with Measures]

There is a number in each of the colored boxes, which is just conditionally formatted for the visualisation purpose. What is required: another table or matrix with the same measures (Rows) but instead of countries - Min and Max Columns (Min- minimum value for each measure in a row from the above table, Max - maximum value for each measure in a row from the above table).

Is this achievable? If yes, are there any suggestions from your side? thank you very much,

Sincerely,

Pavlo

Answer (score 0):

You need a table with 2 values: Min and Max (let's call it MinMaxTable)

And you need 3 new measures, all with the same pattern:

```
Rank Sales EUR (min/max)=
VAR min_or_max = SELECTEDVALUE(MinMaxTable[Min or Max])
VAR tbl = SUMMARIZE(countries, countries[country], "rank", [Rank Sales EUR])

RETURN IF(min_or_max = "Min", MINX(tbl, [rank]), MAXX(tbl, [rank]))
```